# problem with convert text to time in sql server 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008

i have this **Ttime** as  nvarchar(10): "09:52:48" and i have **TmpTime** as date

and i try to convert like this: "UPDATE MEN SET TmpTime   = CONVERT(DATETIME, Ttime ,108 )"

and i get in **TmpTime** this: "1900-01-01"

why ?

thank's in advance

Comment: -1 for not asking correct question for the accepted answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you also have a date field, you should to concatenate them before to cast:

```
CREATE TABLE #Sample ( DateField varchar(10), TimeField varchar(10) );
GO

INSERT INTO  #Sample VALUES ('2009-01-24', '09:52:48');
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, DateField + ' ' + TimeField) as Converted FROM #Sample
```

And you'll get:

```
Converted
-----------------------
2009-01-24 09:52:48.000
```

Comment: oK,
and how to show 2010-01-21 00:00:00.000 as 21/01/2010
and 1900-01-01 09:09:18.000 as 09:09:18

Comment: Gold, they're two different things; do you have that datefield?

Answer (score 0):

You have a column defined as "date" and then you are sending only a time value into it

The date portion defaults to zero which is 01 January 1900 in SQL (in the CONVERT). Then the time is ignored for a date column.

What do you expect to happen?

(The same would happen whether or not you use CONVERT or not because the column is "date")

Comment: i try to convert text to date
i need to get in the date field the value of text field

Comment: Your text is a time. Not a date. What date to you want? Today?if you want date, ask for date. I explianed why you get 01 jan 1900 **which is what you asked for**